# How can I have a fast timer in R?

Tags: r, timer, scheduler

I need to run a loop every 10 milliseconds. I tried these two approaches:

```
#First
library(tcltk2)
tclTaskSchedule(10, f_test(), id='taskId',  redo=TRUE )

#Second
library(later)
timer1 <- function(interval = 0.01) {
  f_test()
  later::later(timer1, interval)
}
timer1()
```

They both were slow. It did run about 200 times in 10 seconds. It is supposed to run 1000 times. The function f_test is fast, it would not be the cause of the delay.

Comment: Something that comes to mind is that perhaps you don't measure every single run but perhaps measure 10 at a time or some such? I'm even thinking from an optimization point of view it probably makes sense to not measure things so quickly

Comment: you're supplying interval in seconds to later. maybe supply it in milliseconds, so 1/100

Comment: You are right, I will change the question.

Comment: Now I did notice that calling "process.events()" helps because it makes the Event Loop run immediately .